# list augmentation in python with numpy or other library

Tags: python, list, numpy, data-augmentation

I would like to augment list from

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

to

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

If I want to augment likewise n times (like 100 or 500 times), how can I do it? I do not want to do it with regular loop, but using some library like numpy. Any helps?

Many thanks.

Comment: do you want each number in the list twice

Comment: With only itertools you could do `list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(x, 2) for x in a))`.

Comment: user3483203 marked my question as duplicate and the answer is what I wanted to know. yatu also answered to my question as well; Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with numpy's [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
np.repeat(a,2)
# array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5])
```

Comment: Please flag obvious duplicates like this as such rather than answering.

Comment: user3483203 // I expected it to be duplicate but I asked the question just because I couldn't find one with the keywords that I thought to be related. Sorry for asking a duplicate question.